# Indefinite Integrals $\tan^3(\theta)$

Tags: calculus

> $$\int 17 \tan^3(x)dx$$

I got $$\frac {17} 2 \Big(\sec^2(x)+2\log(\cos(x))\Big)$$ But apparently this isn't right. I double checked with wolframalpha and it is not right as well.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a derivative, we see that

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{17}{2} \left(\sec^2{x} + 2 \log{\cos{x}}\right) &= 17 \left(\sec{x} \cdot \sec{x} \tan{x} + \frac{1}{\cos{x}} \sin{x}\right) \\
&= 17 \left(\tan{x} \sec^2{x} + \tan{x}\right) \\
&= 17 \tan{x} \left(\sec^2{x} + 1 \right) \\
&= 17 \tan^3{x}
\end{align}

So the given answer is correct. There's a lot of ways to re-write various trigonometric functions using identities, so a direct check of the derivative is likely to be better to look at than Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the tangent half-angle substitution, you arrive to a quite nice integrand. Then, use partial fractions and ... you arrive to the result you gave !

Comment: You can make the substitution y=Cos[x] and use the fact that Sin[x]^2+Cos[x]^2=1 in the numerator. This leads to a very simple integrand in terms of y.